# My exe can not response the "ctrl+c" When I load the dll which contains ACE init.(C++)

Tags: c++, dll, signals, ace

I have a question now, it is about ACE and signal capture. I have a dll which contains ACE init function's call, I need to call this dll in my .exe, but in this case, My exe can not capture the signal of "ctrl+c". if I don't call the ACE init function in the dll ,the question will not exit.so please help me.
thanks.

Comment: Which compiler are you using?

Comment: I used VS2010 ,what may lead to this problem ?thanks